# Configure pcntl_signal on php7.1

Tags: php, php-7.1

I've faced the issue with `pcntl_signal` after migration to php71.

I've installed php71 (`brew install php71 --with-httpd24 --with-imap --with-postgresql`) and its pcntl extension (`brew install homebrew/php/php71-pcntl`) but `pcntl_signal()` still not working

Please help me because i don't understand why it does not work.

**P.S.** I'm running the same code which was working on php56

Answer (score 2):

After some research I found out that a new function called `pcntl_async_signals()` has been introduced in php71, so now instead of `declare(ticks = 1);` at the beginning of the file you have use `pcntl_async_signals(true);`

For my particular case I fixed if like:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Command;

if (function_exists('pcntl_async_signals')) {
    // for php 7.1
    pcntl_async_signals(true);
} else {
    // for php 4.3.0+ (up to 7.0)
    declare(ticks = 1);
}

abstract class AbstractCommand {
    // use pcntl_signal() where you need
}
```

P.S. Link to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.asynchronous-signal-handling)